# Check the array value exist in subscribe angular10

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9, rxjs-observables

Am having some const array values and i have the response value in subscribe and i want to check whether the const array value is availabe in response.i dont know how to use map and filter in subscribe. if the value is available then the checkval should return true other wise false.i can able to did using some function but here i needs to use rxjs operators

```
 Response:
{
    "testLoad": 1603367083993,
    "checkData": "test1"
    "type": "flag",
    "title": "TestFlag",
    "styleId": "test",
    "BodyContent": {
        "properties": "undefined"
    }

}
 

       const styleid: Array<string> = ['test1','test2','test3'];
        public checkVal(){
        this.idVal =this.data.getresponse().subscribe((response => console.log(response ));
       }
```

since am new to angular rxjs can you please guide me and help out from this issue

Comment: Please provide more information about the response. Also "i want to check whether the const array value is availabe in response" can be interpreted several ways, please clarify what exactly means "value is availble in response"

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm i have added the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments I understand, that you want to return a `true` Observable, if the `response.checkData` value is included in the `pageUid` array.

You can do the following:

```
  this.data.getresponse().pipe(
    map(response => pageUid.includes(response.checkData)),
  ).subscribe(checkResult => console.log(checkResult));
```

Comment: Hi is there any possible to instead of subscribe, modify this to observable and use async.if its possible means how can we do that

Comment: Of course this is possible. Just remove the subscription and store the observable

Comment: removing subsribtion means could n't  get you.can you please give some syntax since am new to angular and rxjs

Comment: `checkResult$: Observable<boolean> = this.data.getresponse().pipe(map(response => pageUid.includes(response.checkData)));`   and in template use this observable with the async pipe `<div>Valid: {{ checkResult$ | async }}</div>`

Comment: if i remove subscribtion means it does not return true or false for eg: rxjs.for eg:this.data.getresponse().pipe(
    map(response => pageUid.includes(response.checkData)),
  ) if i remove the subscription means then it not returns true or false

Comment: It returns an Observable with contains the boolean value. With the async pipe you observe this Observable

Comment: it returns object as obseravable but not as boolean

Comment: like this Store {_isScalar: false, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: ReducerManager, source: Store, operator: MapOperator}
actionsObserver: ActionsSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
operator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project: ƒ}
reducerManager: ReducerManager {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
source: Store {_isScalar: false, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject,.

Comment: You can't turn that observable into a plain boolean, since you have an async operation here. Use either the async pipe or assign the boolean in the subscription callback